# how to filter an array using a binary representation of an integer argument?

Tags: java, arrays

[image: helper image]> > A binary representation of a number can be used to select elements from an array. For example,

> ```
>                  n: 88 = 23 + 24 + 26 (1011000)
>                  array: 8, 4, 9, 0, 3, 1, 2
>                indexes: 0  1  2  3  4  5  6
>                  selected        *  *     *
>                    result        0, 3,    2 so the result of filtering {8, 4, 9, 0, 3, 1, 2} using 88 would be {0, 3, 2} In the
> ```
>
> above, the elements that are selected are those whose indices are used
>   as exponents in the binary representation of 88. In other words, a[3],
>   a[4], and a[6] are selected for the result because 3, 4 and 6 are the
>   powers of 2 that sum to 88. Write a method named filterArray that
>   takes an array and a non-negative integer and returns the result of
>   filtering the array using the binary representation of the integer.
>   The returned array must big enough to contain the filtered elements
>   and no bigger. So in the above example, the returned array has length
>   of 3, not 7 (which is the size of the original array.) Futhermore, if
>   the input array is not big enough to contain all the selected
>   elements, then the method returns null. For example, if n=3 is used to
>   filter the array a = {18}, the method should return null because
>   3=20+21 and hence requires that the array have at least 2 elements
>   a[0] and a[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psG1s.png), but there is no a[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psG1s.png). If you are using Java or C#, the
>   signature of the function is int[ ] filterArray(int[ ] a, int n)

[image: add picture]

I have this question I am trying to solve and I wrote this code

```
public static int[] filterArray(int[] a, int n) {
    int[] x = new int[a.length];
    int j = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        int digit = n % 2;
        n /= 2;
        x[j] = digit;
        j++;
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));

    for (int k = 0; k < x.length; k++) {
        if (x[k] == 1)
            count++;
    }

    System.out.println("count is " + count);

    int[] z = new int[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < x.length; k++) {
            if(x[k] == 1) {
                z[i] = a[k];
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(z));
    return x;

}
```

When I try to test is with a test array of

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(filterArray(new int[] { 0, 9, 12, 18, -6 }, 11)));
```

It is giving me the following output

```
[18, 18, 18]
```

the correct output is

```
[0, 9, 18]
```

Comment: Please reformat the citated question. In its current state it's a pain to read. As an example I suspect that instead of `88 = 23 + 24 + 26` (which would be confusing) you mean `88 = 2^3 + 2^4 + 2^6` (you could even use super script html tags which don't work in comments :) ).

Comment: More clear explanation will help a lot

Comment: It seems that the binary representation of 88 (1011000) does not play any role here. Can you confirm? If so, it will be better to remove it from the question to avoid more confusion

Comment: the idea is that the ones from the the binary representation of 88 should match the pattern in the given array and the indices with 1 should be returned in another array with size 3. i. e 0, 3, 2

Comment: Victor has a point: your problem isn't related to the task itself but how you are handling the arrays.

Comment: first I tried to convert n to its base two using a while loop then tried to calculate the count of the new array that holds the returned array and copy the elements from the original array that match the array with values that is equal to 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your nested loops: you're iterating over the entire input array for *each* element of the output array and keep overwriting the values with the last found element (step through your code with a debugger and you'll see that).

To fix that, swap your loops and keep track of the "next" output index:

```
  int i = 0;
  for (int k = 0; k < x.length; k++) {
    if(x[k] == 1) {
        z[i] = a[k];
        i++; //advance the output index
    }
  }
```

That will make your code faster as well since now you don't have O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity but just O(n).